# Is it possible to send a break/stop signal to a method?

Tags: python, oop

I'm currently in the process of writing some server code in python and I have a method which begins an infinite loop to serve requests ie:

```
class s:
    def serve(self):
        while True:
            # do stuff
```

When I call this code I do something like:

```
a = s()
a.serve()
```

My question is -- is there way to send a message to 'serve' to disrupt the loop from outside the method. I don't want to simply kill the program. Help much appreciated.

One option I've thought of is rather than:

```
while True:
    // do something
```

Could do:

```
 while self.serving: # and then update self.serving as appropriate
```

But there's probably a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible:

```
class Server:

    def __init__():
        self.alive = True

    def serve(self):
        while self.alive:
            # do stuff

    def die():
        self.alive = False
```

Now just call `die()` outside the thread running `serve(..)`.

```
srv = Server()
thread = Thread(target=srv.serve)
thread.start()
time.sleep(some_time)  # or do something else.
srv.die()  # or do this from some outside process.
```

Comment: Cool yeah that was my thinking and that makes the most sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do but could you have a simple flag rather than:

```
while True:
```

it could be

```
example = True
while example:
```

Then set example to false when you want to end the loop.

Comment: To clarify; I want to send the signal to the method from outside the method. So, s.stop() needs to make s.start()'s loop break. But potentially yeah, an object accessible paramater is the way to go.